# Controller action - redirect to another template

Tags: forms, redirect, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am looking for a way to redirect to another template if certain conditions are fulfilled.

Like:

```
public funtion redirectAction() {
 if(certain conditions = TRUE){
  REDIRECT TO ANOTHER TEMPLATE WITH DIFFERENT CONTENT
 }
}
```

I've seen some expressions in existing actions:

```
$this->redirect('list');
```

In this case, `'list'` is the default `List.html` template, right?
So I thought if I replaced the `'list'` with a different template name, that would solve the problem. But i get a opps error.

Or is there any other solution of calling a different template?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a redirect in the controller you always redirect to another function, not a template.

For example with

```
$this->redirect('list2');
```

You would then redirect to the function list2Action() and this would expect a Template List2.html

Often however, it is easier to use a switch in fluid.
for example:

```
<f:if condition="{abc} == 1">
<f:then>
   <f:render partial="TempalteAbcTrue" arguments="{_all}" />
</f:then>
<f:else>
    <f:render partial="TempalteAbcFalse" arguments="{_all}" />
</f:else>
```

If you used the normal folder structure of extbase you have a "Layouts", "Templates" and "Partials" folder.
With the example above you can create 2 files in the folder "Partials": "TempalteAbcTrue.html" and "TempalteAbcFalse.html".

Comment: Thank you very much! I just created a new action with a new Template. Now i can use this action in fluid to redirect to another Template. That's exactly what i was looking for.